# Java Long Returning Strange Value

Tags: java, long-integer

Regarding the following method:

```
private long getCountdownLeft(Integer seconds) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedMillis = now - seconds;
        long millisLeft = seconds * 1000 - elapsedMillis;
        return millisLeft/1000;
}   

public static void Main(String[] args) {
      getApi().getLogger.debug("TimeLeft " + getCountDownLeft(3600)); //base time
}
```

It is returning a value of something like: -12039495960, why is that?

Comment: Print out your variables, it seems like your elapsedMillis is a lot bigger than seconds * 1000

Comment: It's also possible he has overflow.

Comment: @Antimony yup, but he without knowing what value is coming in, its hard to tell.

Comment: It's impossible to tell unless you show the value that you pass as `seconds`.

Comment: Yes they are large, what can I do to get a resonable value?

Comment: @user1513909 tell us what kind of values you get for `seconds` so we know how to help.

Comment: You keep changing the code, are you just slapping in random stuff? Tell us what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What is `getCountDownLeft` supposed to do? It's not clear what you're counting down from.

Comment: @ZongLi Yeah, and the purpose of `seconds` is vague also. According to the log, getCountDownLeft is supposed to return `Time Left` in milliseconds before some time in the future, so how do you provide that information, @user1513909.

Answer (score 1):

If 3600 is the value you are passing in, you're obviously going to get a negative value.

Print out `System.currentTimeMillis()`, youll see that it is quite a large value.

`currentTimeMillis()` is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) as:

```
the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely hard to tell based on the information given, but for this method to work, `seconds` must be initialized with `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

Boiled down into one statement, you have

```
    return (seconds * 999 - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000;
```

If `System.currentTimeMillis()` is unix time (1343874904292 right now), then OF COURSE this will be negative.  I'm not sure what you meant to write, but this obviously not it...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are subtracting *seconds* from *milliseconds*.

Try this:

```
long elapsedMillis = now - (seconds * 1000); // convert seconds to millseconds
```

It seems you are really just trying to do this:

```
private long getCountdownLeft(Integer seconds) {
    return seconds * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Im trying to get the difference of the time from an hour by the current state of time.

Comment: each time i invoke the method, "getCountdownLeft()" it should give me the difference of the time from an hour at that moment.